# Undo a git push on the remote branch without changing local repository?

Tags: git

A developer in my team committed his changes to the wrong remote repository. I want to remove what he pushed to this repository on the remote repository. I don't want to change anything locally.

Therefore how can I:

1. List the commits on the remote repository branch so that I can see which commits that have been pushed need to be removed.
2. Remove each of these commits on the remote repository branch so that I can go back to the commit before he pushed his changes.

I am not sure if "removing" is the correct process or if it is meant to be "revert" but in the end I need the remote repository branch to be back to where it was before he pushed his changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mark where that branch was last by

```
git tag original-master origin/master
```

inspect what you get from the server:

```
git fetch

git log --all --graph
```

or

```
gitk --all
```

if your tag still makes sense that that's where the remote branch should be, force push that up:

```
git push -f origin original-master:master
```

if it's another commit, push that commit as the master:

```
git push -f origin <some SHA1>:master
```

clean up:

```
git tag -d original-master
```

update your tracking branches since the fix:

```
git fetch
```

This assumes "master" is the branch in question. Replace "master" with the proper branch name if it's another one.